# How can I duplicate a database from c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a 'base' database that is filled with generic info within various tables. This database is created for each user so that they have their own versions and can modify that same info to suit their needs.

I update the base database with changes so that new users will get the updates when they register.

My app is an MVC3 site on Entity Framework 4.1 using a MySQL back-end.

Currently I do this process above using the following steps:

1. Run a mysqldump on the database to get a .sql file
2. Update the generated file to change the db name to the users name
3. Run a mysql import using the new script

However I have recently migrated over to Azure and this process seems to be very slow compared to the old physical server (similar but slightly higher specs).

Is there a better way I can be doing this that might remove the IO processes and potentially increase the overall speed?

Comment: Why don't you simply just create just ONE database and only safe the user-specific settings? Your approach is a waste of ressources and can easily be avoided by using a proper DB layout with normalized tables.

Comment: You're right that it is a big resource overhead, but I chose this approach for a few reasons: 1) it lets me recover databases individually without having to trawl through every other users data. 2) more secure, if someone gets into their database somehow from the app then all they get is their own data (nothing stopping them from hacking the server itself obviously), and 3) some of the tables can get quite large, so breaking them up was an attempt to speed up some of the large queries (multi-table nested selects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my approach, now I just have a 'Please wait' animation showing while the server does the heavy lifting.